# Django password reset function view

Tags: python, django

Using class based views kind of hide all the complexity in the django code so I prefer using the function based view then afterwards move to class based views.

Is there by any chance you can write a custom password reset view to change user's password either than using django's class based views? I am able to do it with class based views but understanding it, is a problem since all the complexity is hidden. If anyone has a link to an article explaining that in detail I would be glad since google is giving me nothing.

Comment: Hey bro... I'm currently writing a function based view to carry out this functionality where an email will be sent to the user with a url/token. I would want to know if you have any success doing this.

Comment: Okay I will suggest that you ask a question, then notify me with the link to the question

Comment: Nevermind man... I figured it out on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a separate function to change the user's password when you can use the Django built-in User model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(username='your_user_name')
user.set_password('your_password')
user.save()
```

Practice DRY (Don't repeat yourself). If it is available built-in and is feasible you should go with it rather than reinventing it.

Cheers,

Ref: [Django auth system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/)

Comment: Ohk @vivek. thanks for the answer.
I already know of this, sorry if i wasn't specific in asking my question buy i wanted a function based view for password reset with email tokens .